# QGIS automatically making point while drawing polygon without pressing left mouse button

Tags: qgis

When I draw a polygon and leave my mouse on one, does the program automatically draw a point without me pressing the left mouse button. What could be the problem or how can I fix it? I am digitising and this is distorting the polygon structure.
QGIS 3.26

Comment: No, QGIS should not create points that way. If you press left button and drag the mouse then a point is created when button is released. Not even automatic tracing https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#automatic-tracing is that automatic as you describe. It would be nice if you could capture a video about what happens to you.

Comment: :-) it may be an hardware issue... when mouse batteries are getting low, they can emit strange click information (well, usually it is when holding the button clicked down, a click release+click can be emitted)

Answer (score 3):

You probably activated [stream digitizing mode](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#straight-curve-and-stream-digitizing) by accident: you activate/deactive it pressing <kbd>R</kbd> button. In this mode, introduced in QGIS 3.20, QGIS draws in free-hand mode, creating vertices without clicking the mouse what can be very handy, see: [Streaming digitizing mode](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog320/index.html#feature-streaming-digitizing-mode).

To avoid this behaviour, activate `Digitize with segments` in `Advanced Digitizing Toolbar` or press <kbd>R</kbd> to leave Stream Digitizing mode:

[image]